# Does Magento2 work only on Linux OS?

Tags: magento2, windows

I am trying to install Magento2 on my local machine but it is not working properly

It throws the following error:

```
Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in \lib\Magento\Autoload\IncludePath.php on line 56
```

Is it because I am using a Windows server?
Does Magento2 works on Linux only?

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you have Xdebug installed. Try increase the value of xdebug.max_nesting_level in your php.ini:

```
ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 200)
```

http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#max_nesting_level

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what your problem might be, but to answer your question... I can confirm that Magento 2.0 (at least the dev-73 build - the last one I installed) is working on windows. I've successfully installed it on xampp 1.8.3 on windows 7 and on windows 8 (without xampp). Even on xampp on windows XP (may he rest in piece).

Answer (score 2):

As others have already said, Magento 2 will work on Mac, Linux and Windows.  The issue you are experiencing is caused by the default [xdebug max nesting level](http://xdebug.org/docs/basic#max_nesting_level) value of 100.

The error you are seeing will only exist if:

1. Xdebug is installed
2. `xdebug.max_nesting_level` hasn't been increased from the default value

I suggest that you find the php.ini file being used by your server and modify the `xdebug.max_nesting_level` there.

There are a couple of ways that you could figure out which php.ini file is use, assuming that more than one such file exists on your system.

1. You can open up the root level `index.php` file and add `phpinfo(); die();` towards the top of the file.
   Load any page of your Magento instance and look for the row that says "**Loaded Configuration File**", which will tell you the exact path to the file that needs to be modified.
2. You could run `php --ini` from the command line and hope that the loaded configuration file is the same as the one used by your web server.

Open up the php.ini file with your favorite editor, note that you might need to use sudo to edit the file. 
`sudo vim /path/to/your/php.ini`

Look for a line that starts with `xdebug.max_nesting_level`, it might already exist and be explicitly set to the default value. If you find it, update it to a value like 200.

If you don't find such a line, you'll need to add it yourself: 
`xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200`

Save your changes to the file and restart your webserver.  That should fix the error message.